# How do I update telegram bot functions without requiring users to restart with /start command?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

How to update the functions of the bot in telegram, for users? The bot is written, running, but if you add buttons or delete something, it will not be displayed until you send the /start command again. How to make it updated for those users who have already launched the bot? Written in python / telebot

only restarting the bot with the Start command helps

Comment: You have to send one message/command to get it refreshed. Maybe, sending an automated message like "Commands Updated" to the user may refresh without the /start command.

Comment: This will work, but I'm interested in a way without sending an update command. How does the user know that there is something new? He will have to send the command all the time - this is not suitable